# SDWebImageManager issue

Tags: iphone, ios7, sdwebimage

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL 
delegate:self 
options:0 
success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached) {
    _newsimage.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView transitionWithView:_newsimage
                      duration:3.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [_newsimage setImage:image];
                        _newsimage.alpha = 1.0;
                    } completion:NULL];
 }failure:nil];
```

I am using this code to download images through `SDWebImage` library and I am geting this error

```
No visible @interface for 'SDWebImageManager' declares the selector 'downloadWithURL:delegate:options:success:failure:'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not use proper SDWebImage. Download [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and check .
Add "**SDWebImage**" folder into you project and check.

You can also this code to download the image:

```
    [imageViewName setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StrImageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    }];
```

Import **#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"** in you viewcontroller where you use code.

Hope it will resolve your issue. :)

Comment: I am using this library already !? if there is any suggestion i appreciate  this :)

Comment: Check my update ans. You can use code for download the image.

Comment: this code work perfectly thanks :) I have another question | how can I set activity indicator instead of image in placeholder ? I am using some codes and also not work properly

Comment: You can make nil to placeholder image, and take a activityindicator view. Once you completed your block hide the indicator view.